# how to save XML to a file (filename.xml) using libxml2 ?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, libxml2

I've configured libxml2 with `" --with-minimum -with--schemas "` switches (configuration options). 
I am using "xmlNewNode" "xmlAddChild" etc. functions to generate the XML file.
Now, i want to save the XML to a file,  but i didn't find any function to do that.

Of-course, there are plenty of functions (like xmlSaveFile() etc..) in "libxml2 full version" BUT as i said i've configured it with `--minimum` configuration option (b/c of memory constraints).

Any one with help ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

xmlDocDumpMemory will let you get the whoe xml doc as a xmlChar* 

`xmlChar *xmlbuff;

int buffersize;

xmlDocDumpFormatMemory(doc, &xmlbuff, &buffersize, 1);`

after which you can save it as a file using 


 `FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(file, "w+");

    if(!fp){

        printf("Could not open file for writing\n");

        return;

    }

    fprintf(fp, buf);

    fclose(fp);`