# XSLT: xsltApplyStylesheet returns null

Tags: libxslt

I've a xml and xsl file. The output from xsl is just a text i.e if some conditions fail, the result is just a description of the failure. If all the conditions pass, the result is null. If I run this in xsltproc, it works fine.

However, If I run this using libxslt using function xsltApplyStylesheet, I see empty result. The input xml to xsltApplyStylesheet is created dynamically in the code. The xsl file is read using xsltParseStylesheetFile.  (I used xmlDocDumpFormatMemory of both the xml and the output of xsltParseStylesheetFile->doc, both seems to be fine). I tried xsltSaveResultToString after ApplyStylesheet, it doesn't work as well.

What could be possible issue here?

Code Snippet:

```
  xmldoc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST "1.0");
  c = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "Company");
  xmlAddChild(c, node);  //node is another child in XML
  xmlAddChild(c, d);  //d is another child in xml
  xmlDocSetRootElement(xmldoc, c);
  .....

  xsl = xsltParseStylesheetFile("xsl.file");
  ....
  output = xsltApplyStylesheet(xsl, xmldoc, NULL);
  ....
  //output has just "<?xml version="1.0"?>"
```

TIA and appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `xmlDocDumpMemory` to save the file as in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340268/how-to-save-xml-to-a-file-filename-xml-using-libxml2) before applying the stylesheet, and see if that works.

**References**

- [XMLSoft FAQ](http://www.xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html)
- [how to save XML to a file (filename.xml) using libxml2 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340268/1113772)
- [Android - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/android)